# Multiple forms on the same page

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a web page where I created and imbedded the Cognito code for 2 Contact forms.  The forms have the same boxes but I want them to be used independently and have the form info go to each person independently.  So far, it only seem to work as though it was one form.

How do I do this?

Comment: This is a bit more about web development than about using the Cognito web interface for designing the forms, so it's bordering on being off-topic.  However, their support/developer staff is usually monitoring the tag, so I will leave it for the time being to see if it is in fact answerable via something in their web app.

Comment: For those of you who want to add their own CSS to their framed contact form - we at least can do it this way:  [Click Here - Iframe embedding](http://help.cognitoforms.com/iframe-embedding)

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). The reason that only one form is working is because we only support the use of one form on a page. One way to work around this is to place a second form inside of an iframe on your webpage.

Comment: Thank you!  I wondered if that was a limitation.  Other than that, this is the greatest service ever!

Comment: With all the respect to this concept - it limits the flexibility to a degree and adds unnecessary complexity. Why not just make it optional? That way if I choose to go the multiform per page route that is on me.

Comment: As the styling options for Cognito forms are limited, I write a bunch of css to overrule the .cognito styles. With the second form in an iframe, it becomes harder to apply the custom styles. It would be more convenient to have both forms loaded inline.